# trying to a lag a column in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table where rows represent individuals in a point in time. I am trying create a column (`statusLag`) with the lagged values of another column (`status`), like so:

```
workerID    timeVar     status      statusLag
---------------------------------------------
1           1           0           NULL
1           2           1           0
1           3           1           1
1           4           1           1
----------------------------------------------
2           3           1           NULL
2           4           0           1
2           5           1           0
2           6           0           1
```

### What I have tried

Doing the following fails (leaves the column unchanged), and I can't understand why

```sql
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN statusLag INTEGER;    

INSERT INTO myTable (statusLag)
    SELECT 
        (SELECT t2.status
            FROM myTable t2
            WHERE t2.workerID = t1.workerID AND
                  t2.timeVar < t1.timeVar
            ORDER BY t2.timeVar desc
            LIMIT 1)
    FROM myTable t1;
```

I almost achieve what I want by creating a new table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myOtherTable
    (   'workerID'  REAL NOT NULL,
        'timeVar'   INTEGER NOT NULL,
        'statusLag' INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY('workerID', 'timeVar')
    )

INSERT INTO myOtherTable
SELECT t1.workerID, t1.timeVar, 
    (SELECT t2.status
        FROM myTable t2
        WHERE t2.workerID = t1.workerID AND
              t2.timeVar < t1.timeVar
        ORDER BY t2.timeVar desc
        LIMIT 1)
FROM myTable t1;
```

To achieve what I want, I would need to join `myOtherTable` with `myTable`. But this looks quite inefficient to me.

So my questions are: Why didn't my first attempt work? And How do I achieve what I want in a more efficient way?

Comment: `INSERT INTO myTable (statusLag)...` will leave workerID, timeVar, and status as null. You need an update statement, not an insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because you inserted new *rows* with the information rather than *updating* existing rows.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET statusLag = (SELECT t2.status
                     FROM myTable t2
                     WHERE t2.workerID = myTable.workerID AND
                           t2.timeVar < myTable.timeVar
                     ORDER BY t2.timeVar desc
                     LIMIT 1
                    );
```